# finding a power series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ centered at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series, advice

In an exercise I am asked to find a power series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ centered at $0$.

My approach was the following:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1-z^2}{(1+z^2)(1-z^2)}=(1-z^2)\frac{1}{1-z^4}=(1-z^2)\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n}$

But this does not seem right because a power series is defined as $\sum a_n(z-a)^n$ and I have something like: $\sum a_n(z-a)^{kn}$, plus I don't know how to pull that $(1-z^2)$ inside the sum.

---

So how can I write this function as a power series?

Usually what is the main approach when trying to write a function as a power or as a Laurent series? Because I allays find myself having some trouble doing so.

---

Edit:

I just realized that we can continue to manipulate this expression: $(1-z^2)\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n}$

$$(1-z^2)\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n}=\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n} - z^2\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n}=$$

$$\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n} -\sum_{n\geq0}z^{4n+2}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n z^{2n}$$

Comment: $1/(1-r) = 1 + r + r^2 + \cdots $; Put $r = -z^2$.

Comment: "But this does not seem right...I have something like". Note that something like $\sum z^{4n}$ is a power-series! It is $1 + 0\cdot z + 0\cdot z^2 + 0\cdot z^3 + 1\cdot z^4 + \ldots$ so if we were to define $a_n = \{1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,\ldots\}$ then it would be on the form $\sum a_n z^n$. Any series where the terms are integer powers of $z$ is a power-series.

Comment: You're right. I did not considered that @Winther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1 {1+z^{2}}=1-z^{2}+z^{4}-z^{6}+...$ for $|z| <1$. RHS is a geometric sum and this is special case of the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: But then the result would be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^{2n}$. Does that count as a power series? Because a power series is defined as: $\sum a_n(z-a)^{n}$ and in this example this series would be of the form: $\sum a_n(z-a)^{kn}$ with $k=2$.

Comment: I guess if in $\sum a_n(z-a)^{n}$ we define $a_n$ to be $0$ if $n$ is add and $(-1)^{n/2}$ if even then we would get $\sum a_n z^{n}=\sum (-1)^n z^{2n}$

Comment: @Eduude Yes, that is correct.

Comment: How do you usually approach this type of problems were you need to find a power series? Because I never know how to start what that to look for in the function. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: As far as I can see you already had the idea since you did use geometric series for $\frac 1 {1-z^{4}}$. You made things a little complicated because you somehow thought that $\sum (-1)^{n}z^{2n}$ wouldn't be a power series around $0$.